# How to delete GPG key and repository? Key is not shown under apt-key

Tags: repository, gnupg, keyrings

I wanted to install ctop on Ubuntu 22 and added the key and repository. But the repository does not contain a release file and apparently ctop is no longer maintained.

Now I wanted to delete the key and repository, but key is not displayed via sudo apt-key list.

How do I delete the key + repository properly? I see that key in "/usr/share/keyrings"

I used these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
curl -fsSL https://azlux.fr/repo.gpg.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/azlux-archive-keyring.gpg
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/azlux-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.azlux.fr/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azlux.list >/dev/null
sudo apt-get update
```

Source: https://github.com/bcicen/ctop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: I opened a link you provided & can see very quickly it provides support for Debian releases only; but you state you're using Ubuntu and haven't made allowance for that.  Your release details show 22 (*Ubuntu Core 22 is the snap only version of 22.04 but cannot use all packages built for 22.04!*) which is unclear so please be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use `add-apt-repository -r` , but https://github.com/bcicen/ctop?tab=readme-ov-file#debianubuntu does not appear to be a PPA. Looking at the installation steps, we can just reverse them:

1. `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ /usr/share/keyrings/azlux-archive-keyring.gpg /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azlux.list`
2. `sudo apt update`